# Shortest way of counting?

Tags: python, count, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of `MyClass`. I want to count the number of elements which have `MyClass.SomeProperty` set to `True` (assuming `SomeProperty` is a boolean which is always `True` or `False`). My concerns are:

- It should run fast
- The code should not be confusing to read
- It should work for any kind of condition (not just booleans)

I know I can do:

```
count = len([e for e in MyList if e.SomeProperty])  # For non booleans, something like e.SomeProperty == MyValue
```

But it seems inefficient.

- Why type a meaningless thing like `e for e`?
- Why create a whole list when you just want to count them?

Is it possible to do better?

Comment: *I know I can do* - No, that won't work.

Comment: Instead of a comprehension, you could just use a for loop. `for e in MyList: if e.SomeProperty: DO SOMETHING`

Comment: @vaultah How come? I just tried out `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; len([i for i in x if i % 2 == 0])` and it's giving the correct result. Same with `x = [True,True,True,False,False,False,False]; len([i for i in x if i])`.

Comment: @Superbest: The code in your question doesn't have the brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sum` with a generator expression.

```
count = sum( e.SomeProperty for e in MyList )
```

Or for a general predicate `p`:

```
count = sum( p(e) for e in MyList )
```

This makes use of the fact True and False can be used as the integers 1 and 0, and the fact a generator is used will prevent a new list from being created.

If you insist on avoiding the `for e in` part, you can use `map` and [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
import opertor
count = sum(map(operator.attrgetter('SomeProperty'), MyList))
```

Or for a general predicate `p`:

```
count = sum(map(p, MyList))
```

However, this is less pythonic. I'd recommend the first approach.

Comment: "It should work for any kind of condition (not just booleans)" We can't take the shortcut that True evaluates to 1 and False to 0.

Comment: @Shashank I clarified how to apply the two approaches to any kind of condition.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you meant:

```
count = sum(bool(e.SomeProperty) for e in MyList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the others but slightly more Pythonic imho:

```
sum(1 for e in MyList if e.SomeProperty)
```

Or if you don't care about being lazy:

```
len([e for e in MyList if e.SomeProperty])
```